# calculate new random number considering distribution of already existing numbers in r

Tags: r, random, distribution

I have a dataframe with participants and I want to randomly assign them to a group (0,1). Each group should have approximately the same amount of participants.
My problem: I will keep adding participants. So, when I calculate a new random number for that participant, it should take into accound the distribution of the random numbers I already have.

This is my code:

```
groupData <- data.frame(participant = c(1), Group = floor(runif(1, min=0, max=2))) 
groupData[nrow(groupData) + 1,] = c(2,floor(runif(1, min=0, max=2))) # with this I will be adding participants
```

Comment: The comment char in R is `#`, not `//`.

Comment: If you're random sampling, on average, you should get two groups of approx. the same size. You can also use `rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, p = 0.5)` instead of `runif`.

Comment: Roman's point is well-taken.  If  you try to "force" balancing during a run, you may well wander into the equivalent of open-loop instability.    Recognize that expectation values apply to the "infinite population" and **any** finite sample is likely to deviate to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're saying is that when iteratively adding participants to `groupData`, you want to randomly assign them to a group such that over time, the groups will be evenly distributed.

> *N.B., iteratively adding rows to a frame scales horribly, so if you're doing this with a lot of data, it will slow down a lot. See "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).*

We can *weight* the different groups proportion to their relative size (inversely), so that a new participant has a slightly-higher likelihood of being assigned an under-populated group.

For instance, if we already have 100 participants with unbalanced groups:

```r
set.seed(42)
groupData <- data.frame(participant = 1:100, Group = sample(c(rep(0, 70), rep(1, 30))))
head(groupData)
#   participant Group
# 1           1     0
# 2           2     0
# 3           3     0
# 4           4     1
# 5           5     0
# 6           6     1

table(groupData$Group)
#  0  1 
# 70 30
```

then we can prioritize the under-filled group using

```r
100 / (table(c(0:1, groupData$Group))-1)
#        0        1 
# 1.428571 3.333333
```

which can be used with `sample` as in

```r
sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = 100 / (table(c(0:1, groupData$Group)) - 1) )
```

I use `table(c(0:1, ..)) - 1` because I want this to work when there may not yet be participants in one of the groups; by concatenating `0:1` to it, I ensure heac group has at least one, and the "minus one" compensates for this artificiality, trying to keep the ratios unbiased.

To "prove" that this eventually rounds out ...

```r
for (pa in 101:400) {
  newgroup <- sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = 100 / (table(c(0:1, groupData$Group))-1))
  groupData <- rbind(groupData, data.frame(participant=pa, Group=newgroup))
}
library(ggplot2)
transform(groupData, GroupDiff = cumsum(Group == 0) - cumsum(Group == 1)) |>
  ggplot(aes(participant, y = GroupDiff)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 100) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(participant=101, GroupDiff=c(-Inf, -1, 1), vjust=c(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), label=c("Start of group-balancing", "Group0-heavy", "Group1-heavy")), hjust=0, aes(label=label, vjust=vjust))
```

[image]

It is possible (even *likely*) that the balance will sway from side-to-side, but in general (asymptotically) it should stay balanced.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that the simplest method is just to assign people in pairs.  Draw a random number (0 or 1) assign person  N to the group associated with that value and assign person N+1 to the other group.  That guarantees random assignment as well as perfectly equal group sizes.

Whether this properly simulates the situation you want to analyze is a separate issue.